# Oversized images with wkhtmltoimage when "--width" => 1140

Tags: php, ubuntu, centos, wkhtmltopdf

Bit of a weird issue.
I'm generating some HTML reports and then, due to Outlook 2010's limitations of understanding CSS/HTML/Images, I'm sending the whole damn report out as an image.

The generation works fine. Previewing the generated HTML in a browser looks lovely at a range of resolutions. However, WKHTMLTOPDF (or rather, wkhtmltoimage) is giving me some odd behaviour with it's --width flag.

I have the following PHP code:

```
# Converts a .html file to a .jpg file - requires wkhtmltopdf installed:
# http://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html
function html_to_jpg($fileIn, $fileOut) {
    echo "\nRendering HTML to image\n";
    $command = 'wkhtmltoimage --width 1130 ' . $fileIn . ' ' . $fileOut;
    $remove = 'rm -f ' . filter_var($fileOut, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    try {
        exec($remove);
        exec($command);
        return true;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

This works. It generates an image of "1130" width as specified. However, the report looks a little dodgy at that width, so I increase the --width...

```
$command = 'wkhtmltoimage --width 1140 ' . $fileIn . ' ' . $fileOut;
```

Now this still generates an image, however, the image is now 36480 pixels wide, with the content centered, and a stack of black space on the right.

Through experimentation I've confirmed that widths < 1140 do not generate this problem, but every width above does. I've confirmed this on Ubuntu 15.10 Wily, and CentOS 6.7, both installed from different RPMs.

Has anyone else experienced this? Am I doing something stupid (other than using exec)?

Answer (score -1):

I have experienced the same behavior, and I fixed it by changing the width of the html element to match the width that I pass in the command and it works fine

so basically in your $fileIn add this in a style tag

```css
html, body {
  width:1140px !important;
}
```

of course you can ommit the !important if nothing else affects the width of these elements in your file.